# Httpd.conf RedirectMatch not Working

Tags: regex, httpd.conf

I have a Java webapp running on tomcat displayed through an AJP connector.
The app's source code is closed so I cant really move much to it. Issue is as following.
When I signout of the app it takes me to a weird looking page. So I want to redirect that strange looking page via the httpd.conf to the sign up page.

The URL has this at the very end, so I identified the URL pattern and wrote a regular expression that matches the pattern , and then wrote it in the httpd.conf and httpd-ssl as well , but it takes no action.

This is what I wrote to the files mentioned above.

RedirectMatch permanent /(?:.*\&sso_signoff=yes) https://mydomain.org/

I believe the proper modules are loaded because if I type not valid regexp and then restart httpd it shows an error conceirning that. Does anyone have idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What URL are you trying to match?

Comment: https://mydomain.org/238246?p_action=sendTopFrame&p_option=security.LoginDisplay&sso_signoff=yes

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're matching query string which cannot be done in `RedirectMatch`. Use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &sso_signoff=yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.org/? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Glad to know, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.